# Hide the empty space below the text

Tags: html, css

please visit : [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-battle-station-multicolor.html) ,you can see :

[image]

please enter zip code : 110001 , than click on "check" button, you can see :

[image]

I want to hide the empty space below this text : "Available with 14 sellers".

I tried giving different values in below code , but it did't worked:

```
.block-shipping-results .block-content dl dd { 
display: inline-block;
/*line-height: 50px;*/
height:100px;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following css:

```
dl, p, ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

And change `.vship1` to `position: absolute;` instead of `position:relative;`

Comment: please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545936/display-background-color-for-the-page-align-texts-at-center

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe i think your issue solved from given answers.

Answer (score 1):

Set height of .block-content or remove all padding/margin from parents/children of Available with 14 sellers at 110001

.

```
.block-content
{
  height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify these Css classes:

```
ul, ol, dl, p, address, blockquote {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

dl dd {
    margin: 0;
}

.check_delivery .block-content {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    .block-shipping-results .block-content dl {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .block-shipping-results .block-content ul {
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
    }
    .block-shipping-results .block-content p {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .vship1 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 90px;
    }
```

Comment: resetting margin globally at this stage can affect other places. so use specific scope.